# Is the complex plane open in the extended complex plane?

Tags: complex-analysis

This kind of matter always confuses me. Is the complex plane open in the extended complex plane? I guess the answer is yes, but can't prove it rigorously. Also if the plane is open in the extended plane, then are open sets of the plane also open in the extended plane? Could anyone provide me with a definite answer?

Comment: Yes, and yes.${}$

Comment: What can you say about the topological structure , I think both will have the same topological structure,if that's the case the. It is quite easy to prove..

Comment: What is your definition of the topology on the extended plane? We need to know that for  a more exact answer.

Comment: It is regarded as the one-point compactification of the plane. That is, the extended complex plane is homeomorphic to the 3 dimensional unit sphere.

Comment: So then for $S^2 \subseteq \mathbb{R}^3$ you need to show that $S^2 \setminus \{p\}$ is open in $S^2$, which is clear, as all singleton sets are closed in any metric space.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, to both. If $z \in \mathbb{C}$ then $B(z,r) \subseteq \mathbb{C}$ for all $r>0$, it cannot contain $\infty$. This shows that $\mathbb{C}$ is open in $\mathbb{C} \cup \{\infty\}$ and all open subsets of $\mathbb{C}$ are open in it too (as unions of open balls).

Answer (score 0):

Yes then you can prove it by contradiction, suppose C is not an open subset of C∪{∞}   then there exist some point say x in C such that any open ball of radius r around x is not completely inside of C which implies, that open ball contains the point at infinity which is a contradiction to our assumption . Hence the result follows...